# Which is correct? They have been married for 5 years. They have been married 5 years

Tags: grammar

I have learnt I have to use the word "for". But in an English lesson the teacher said, "They have been married 5 years". Is this sentence correct without "for" before the number?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: The version without "for" is perfectly acceptable. It's common to leave out words that are understood. For example: A: How long have you been married? B: It's been five years.

Comment: Thank you for the responds.

Comment: "responses", not "responds" ;)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, Cody. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. There is not even a real difference in meaning between them. I would say that using 'for' is perhaps a touch more formal.